# Are these compound, complex, or simple?

Tags: sentence-construction

Can someone please help me find the sentence type for these sentences? They should either be simple, compound, or complex. I have taken a look at these and I find it difficult.

- 1. "This is an excellent Turkey, I usually do not enjoy poultry at
     all, I have ever eaten.
- 2. Two dogs and a cat gathered around the fallen trash can and ate their
     dinner.
- 3. As we were running for all we were worth, the grizzly bursts out from
     the bush with snarling roar as it rose on its hind legs to bar out
     escape.
- 4. I had hoped we could make it out of the woods before sundown, yet we
     were still a mile away from the road as the last of the sun slipped
     behind the trees.
- 5. I have heard the same question asked by three different people today
     because you will not listen to the answers when they are given.

Comment: Anyone?!? Any help would be appreciated. I'm really stuck at these.

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not a grammatical sentence, nor does it make sense.
2. This is a complex sentence because "and ate their dinner" has no subject, so it is a *dependent* clause using the subject of the previous *independent* clause. A complex sentence has one independent clause and at least on dependent clause.
3. Complex, because the "As" is a subordinate conjunction.
4. Look up "yet" to determine if it is subordinate or correlative.
5. Look up the conjunction "because" to determine if it is subordinate or correlative.